# One object flink operator (ex. Filter) or two objects in Apache Flink Job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I have Apache Flink Job with 4 input DataStreams (JSON messages) from separate Apache Kafka topics and I've only one object XFilterFunction - which does some filtering. I wrote some data pipeline logics (for primitive example):

```
FilterFunction<MyEvent> xFilter = new XFilterFunction();

inputDataStream1.filter(xFilter)
.name("Xfilter")
.uid("Xfilter");

inputDataStream2
.union(inputDataStream3)
//here some logics (map, process,...)
.filter(xFilter);
```

Is it good or bad practice to use one new object XFilterFunction in Job? 
Or better to use two new objects XFilterFunction? (2 streams -> 2 new filter objects)

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate the class several times i.e.

```
inputDataStream1.filter(new XFilterFunction());
...
inputDataStream2.filter(new XFilterFunction());
```

there should be not problem. I'm not so sure if otherwise things like state or overridden contextual functions would show unwanted behaviour.
In case it's no specialization of `RichFunction`, maybe there's even just a pure function invocation happening via delegates, unfortunately I'm not that deep into Flink's internals to say, but with solution above, you should be safe.